# How Do I Call Seperate C# file into my C# program?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to add a separate `C#` file into my `C#` program. There is no forums on it. Example: Run `hello.cs` code inside `woow.cs`

Comment: Please share the code that you currently have.  I presume that you have written your "hello world" program, and want to refactor this into a reusable component.

Comment: are you using visual studio ?

Comment: Are you wanting to load a non-compiled C# source file at runtime? Sounds like you want runtime compilation if that’s the case.

Comment: Hi @NightOwl, as you can see from various responses, your readers are struggling to understand what it is you are trying to do.  Partly that's because words like 'add' and  'run' can be interpreted in several different ways.  The page [ask] offers some useful advice on how to ask good questions.  Since you are asking a How-To question it may help your readers if you update your post to show the version of IDE you are using - for example by adding tags like [tag:visual-studio-2017].  The answer may change depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is public simply reference to Project1 from Project2

```
RightClick->Add->References->Projects
```

Add a using to the namespace the class lives E.g

```
using MyHelloWordApp.Program;
```

The call the method you want (if its all public)

---

If you want to do this at runtime, then (which i dont think you want), you could use

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Blahblahblah.dll");

var type = assembly.GetType("SomeName.HelloWorld");
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.Output(@"SomeMethod");
```

> **Note** : Both these options are assuming you either have access to the
>   project or assembly.

Comment: OP is asking about a plain .cs file